# MySQL Stored Procedure if statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
DECLARE vote_id INT;
    select id from votes where votes.question_id = question_id and vote_type_id = 3 into vote_id;

    if vote_id is null then
      ...do A
    else
      ...do B
    end if;
```

the condition should be true and execute A part of code but always execute B part.
How to use select with if statement? Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe `vote_id` is never null as per your query?

Comment: I execute the 'select id...' in mysql and return id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `select id from votes where votes.question_id = question_id and votes.vote_type_id = 3 into vote_id;`